# Extract email addresses using vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a large log file that contains email addresses mixed in with some other content.  Each line contains an email address as well as some other text, like:

I can match the email addresses in vim but I'd like to remove all the content that doesn't match an email address, leaving me with a single address per line.  How can I do that with a regex search?

Comment: try grep '.com' <file-name>

Comment: Using `grep --only-matching` is probably the easiest method

Answer (score 0):

if you have already successfully matched the email address, you can do :

```
:%s/.\{-}\(yourPattern\).*/\1/g
```

for example:

```
%s/.\{-}\(\S\+@\S\+\).*/\1/
```

here the `\S\+@\S\+` is the pattern. for sure it is not the good try for matching an email address.